# How to cast an ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation when using STI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to 'cast' a set of records from an association to its STI sub-class.

```
# Parent class
class Basket < AR::Base
  has_many :fruits
end

# Base STI class
class Fruit < AR::Base
  belongs_to :basket
  scope :coconuts, -> { where type: 'Coconut' }
end

# Child STIs classes
class Banana < Fruit
end

class Coconut < Fruit
end
```

The goal is to get an `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation` of `Coconut` objects, through the `Fruit#coconuts` scope. The problem is that the association returned by my queries are always composed of `Fruit` objects.

```
Basket.first.fruits.coconuts.class.name
=> "ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation"

Basket.first.fruits.coconuts.arel.engine.name
=> "Fruit"
```

I am missing a link, in order to cast my result-set into objects instantiated from the Coconut class.

Any hint appreciated. Thanks

Comment: write `class Coconut < Fruit; scope ; scope coconuts:, -> { all } ; end` and you will get what you want. Move your method from `Fruit` to `Coconut`

Comment: Still the same, `Basket.first.fruits.coconuts.arel.engine.name` returns `"Fruit"`

Comment: Moving the method from `Fruit` to `Coconut` raises a NoMethodError

Answer (score 0):

you can use `becomes` per object.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/becomes

Comment: Thanks. `becomes` works on the record object, but my question is about the association itself (the result-set of records)

Comment: You can redefining your relations the other way, though it is not "casting". so that on basket you do something like `has_many :coconuts, source: :fruits, class_name: 'Coconut'`

Comment: I thought about that (defining scope in the `Basket` model) but in reality Basket is a polymorphic association to Fruit; which mean this solution is bug-prone